# Area of a hexagon from the distances of the opposite sides

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

**Problem.** *All the six sides of the hexagon in the attached figure have equal length, and the opposite sides are parallel. The distances of the three opposite pairs are $d_1=7\mathrm{cm}$, $d_2=8\mathrm{cm}$ and $d_3=9\mathrm{cm}$, respectively. Find the area of the hexagon.*

Clearly, 
$$
\text{Area}=\frac{1}{2}x(d_1+d_2+d_3),
$$ 
where $x$ is the length of each of the sides. Hence, it suffices to find $x$ as a function of $d_1,d_2$ and $d_3$.

**EDIT.** The area in the particular case $d_1=7\mathrm{cm}$, $d_2=8\mathrm{cm}$ and $d_3=9\mathrm{cm}$ is provided in the answer of Jack D'Aurizio that follows. I was wondering whether it is possible to obtain an expression the area of the hexagon as a function of $d_1,d_2$ and $d_3$.

[image]

Comment: What is your question? You want us to find the relationship between $x$ and $d_1,d_2,d_3$?

Comment: @Théophile I have corrected the formulation of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Nilknarf The problem is to find the area of the hexagon, as a function of $d_1,d_2$ and $d_3$.

Comment: This was a puzzle I formulated and posed on my website in 2015: http://www.elliottline.com/puzzles-1/2015/11/6/puzzle-of-the-week-22-hex-agony

Comment: I then worked with Presh Talwalker to produce a YouTube video of the same problem but with different parallel distances: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yy1EV9XCbtw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend every other edge of the hexagon (of side-length $s$) to determine three points $A$, $B$, $C$; define $a := |BC|$, $b := |CA|$, $c := |AB|$.

Note that the parallel edges of the hexagon give rise to similar triangles. The figure labels segments according to the appropriate proportions.

[image]

Now, consider the hexagon's opposite-edge distance $k$. By similarity, we can write (with $T := |\triangle ABC|$)

$$\frac{|BB_c|}{|BC|} = \frac{k}{\text{altitude from $C$}} \quad\to\quad
\frac{s(a+b)}{ab} = \frac{k}{2T/c} \quad\to\quad a b ck=2Ts(a+b) \tag{1} $$
Likewise,
$$a b c h = 2 T s (b+c) \qquad a b c j = 2 T s (c+a) \tag{2}$$

Thus,

$$h : j : k \;=\; b+c:c+a:a+b \tag{3}$$

and we deduce that, for some $\lambda$,

$$a = (-h + j + k)\lambda \qquad b = (h-j+k)\lambda \qquad c = (h+j-k)\lambda \tag{4}$$
so that, by Heron's Formula, 
$$\begin{align}
T &=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{\lambda^2}{4}\sqrt{(h+j+k)(3h-j-k)(3j-k-h)(3k-h-j)}
\end{align} \tag{5}$$
Finally, substituting $(4)$ and $(5)$ back into $(1)$:

> $$s =\frac{(-h+j+k)(h-j+k)(h+j-k)}{\sqrt{(h+j+k)(3h-j-k)(3j-k-h)(3k-h-j)}} \tag{6}$$

The hexagon's area follows immediately. $\square$

Comment: Extremely elegant, and purely Euclidean - no trigonometry used!

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: I'm quite pleased with how this came together. My first couple of passes were algebraic messes, requiring a great deal of symbol-pushing assistance from *Mathematica*. Introducing some trig helped, but not enough. Once I started wondering if the Heron-like factors in the result were trying to tell me to focus on triangle areas, I discovered the similarity-based argument. In retrospect, maybe that should've been an "obvious" approach, but it wasn't at the time.

Answer (score 3):

The general problem is not easy at all: in some cases, it is best to take the problem poser point of view. How would you construct a simple equilateral hexagon with parallel opposite sides? My inspired guess was to exploit the $(3,4,5)$ Pythagorean triple:

[image]

and I was so lucky that I met the exact constraints on the distances of opposite sides.
From the above diagram it is trivial to get that the side length is $5$ and the wanted area is

$$ 25+25-2+6+6 = \frac{5}{2}(7+8+9) = \color{red}{60}.$$

Comment: Amazing! Very nice solution! (+1)

Comment: Can you obtain an answer for general values of $d_1,d_2$ and $d_3$?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: I am quite confident that I can do that, but it will take me some time. Keep tuned for updates.

Comment: Approach: assuming that the hexagon side length is one and embedding the construction in the complex plane we may also assume that four consecutive vertices of the haxagon are given by $1,0,e^{i\alpha}, e^{i\alpha}-e^{i(\alpha+\beta)}$ and the common midpoint of the diagonals is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{i\alpha}-\frac{1}{2}e^{i(\alpha+\beta)}$.

Comment: I think it remains to prove that this is the only solution!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Jack D'Aurizo's suggestion, consider embedding our hexagon into $\mathbb{C}$ by placing one vertex at $z=0$, another at $z=r$, and a third at $z=re^{i\alpha}$, where $r$ is the common length of the six sides.

[image: a hexagon embedded in the complex plane]

The leftmost vertex in the above figure is at $z=re^{i\alpha}$, so the vertex that forms the left endpoint of the top horizontal side is at $z=re^{i\alpha}+re^{i\pi-\beta}$, since the top-left side must be parallel to the bottom-right side.  The imaginary part of this vertex will give us the distance from the bottom horizontal side to the top horizontal side, which we call $d_1$.  So we have
\begin{equation}
d_1 = \Im(r(e^{i\alpha}+e^{i(\pi-\beta)})) = r(\sin\alpha + \sin(\pi-\beta)) = r(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta).
\end{equation}
Denoting the distance from the bottom-left side to the top-right side by $d_2$ and the distance from the top-left side to the bottom-right side by $d_3$, we similarly see that
\begin{equation}
d_2 = r(\sin\alpha+\sin\gamma)
\quad\text{and}\quad
d_3 = r(\sin\beta+\sin\gamma).
\end{equation}
(**Edit:** We didn't have to embed into $\mathbb{C}$ to get these equations.  We could also have drawn a horizontal line through the leftmost vertex and vertical lines through the other two left-hand vertices, then computed the heights of the two resulting triangles.)  Now we can start getting tricky.  Since we expect $d_1,d_2$, and $d_3$ to determine many (perhaps all) of the properties of our hexagon, let's compute the angles from these distances.  We have
\begin{align*}
d_1+d_2-d_3 &= 2r\sin\alpha\\
d_1-d_2+d_3 &= 2r\sin\beta\\
-d_1+d_2+d_3 &= 2r\sin\gamma,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= \arcsin\left(\frac{d_1+d_2-d_3}{2r}\right)\\
\beta &= \arcsin\left(\frac{d_1-d_2+d_3}{2r}\right)\\
\gamma &= \arcsin\left(\frac{-d_1+d_2+d_3}{2r}\right).
\end{align*}
Because the opposite sides of our hexagon are parallel, opposite angles must agree.  This means that $4\pi=2\alpha+2\beta+2\gamma$, so
\begin{equation}
2\pi = \arcsin\left(\frac{d_1+d_2-d_3}{2r}\right) + \arcsin\left(\frac{d_1-d_2+d_3}{2r}\right) + \arcsin\left(\frac{-d_1+d_2+d_3}{2r}\right).
\end{equation}
We can get some traction here by using the following addition formula:
\begin{align*}
\arcsin x &+ \arcsin y + \arcsin z\\ &= \arcsin\left(x\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{1-z^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-z^2} + z\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}-xyz\right).
\end{align*}
Applying this to our above equation and multiplying through by $8r^3$ yields
\begin{align*}
0 = (d_1 &+d_2 - d_3)\sqrt{4r^2-(d_1-d_2+d_3)^2}\sqrt{4r^2-(-d_1+d_2+d_3)^2}\\
&+(d_1 - d_2 + d_3)\sqrt{4r^2-(d_1+d_2-d_3)^2}\sqrt{4r^2-(-d_1+d_2+d_3)^2}\\
&+(-d_1 + d_2 + d_3)\sqrt{4r^2-(d_1+d_2-d_3)^2}\sqrt{4r^2-(d_1d_2+d_3)^2}\\
&-(d_1+d_2-d_3)(d_1-d_2+d_3)(-d_1+d_2+d_3).
\end{align*}
This equation can be rearranged to produce
\begin{align*}
1&= \frac{\sqrt{4r^2-(d_1-d_2+d_3)^2}}{d_1-d_2+d_3}\frac{\sqrt{4r^2-(-d_1+d_2+d_3)^2}}{-d_1+d_2+d_3} + \frac{\sqrt{4r^2-(d_1+d_2-d_3)^2}}{d_1+d_2-d_3}\frac{\sqrt{4r^2-(-d_1+d_2+d_3)^2}}{-d_1+d_2+d_3} + \frac{\sqrt{4r^2-(d_1+d_2-d_3)^2}}{d_1+d_2-d_3}\frac{\sqrt{4r^2-(d_1-d_2+d_3)^2}}{d_1-d_2+d_3}.
\end{align*}
This seems like a good place to hand things over to a computer algebra system.  I asked *Mathematica* to solve
\begin{equation}
1 = \frac{\sqrt{4r^2-x^2}}{x}\frac{\sqrt{4r^2-y^2}}{y}+\frac{\sqrt{4r^2-x^2}}{x}\frac{\sqrt{4r^2-z^2}}{z} + \frac{\sqrt{4r^2-y^2}}{y}\frac{\sqrt{4r^2-z^2}}{z}
\end{equation}
for $r$ in terms of $x$, $y$, and $z$.  The result was
\begin{equation}
r = \frac{xyz}{\sqrt{-x^4+2x^2y^2-y^4+2x^2z^2+2y^2z^2-z^4}} = \frac{xyz}{\sqrt{(x+y+z)(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)}}.
\end{equation}
We can then make the substitutions $x=d_1+d_2-d_3$, $y=d_1-d_2+d_3$, and $z=-d_1+d_2+d_3$ to obtain the following expression for $r$ in terms of the distances:
\begin{equation}
\boxed{r = \frac{(-d_1 + d_2 + d_3) (d_1 + d_2 - d_3) (d_1 - d_2 + d_3)}{\sqrt{(d_1+d_2+d_3)(3d_1-d_2-d_3)(3d_2-d_3-d_1)(3d_3-d_1-d_2)}}.}
\end{equation}
(Thanks to Blue for simplifying these expressions!)  The area of the hexagon will thus be
\begin{equation}
\boxed{A = \frac{1}{2}r(d_1+d_2+d_3) = \frac{(-d_1 + d_2 + d_3) (d_1 + d_2 - d_3) (d_1 - d_2 + d_3)\sqrt{d_1+d_2+d_3}}{2\sqrt{(3d_1-d_2-d_3)(3d_2-d_3-d_1)(3d_3-d_1-d_2)}}.}
\end{equation}
It's worth pointing out that in our case we have $d_1=9$, $d_2=8$, and $d_3=7$ (up to some permutation of labels), so
\begin{equation}
r = \frac{(6)(8)(10)}{\sqrt{(24)(12)(8)(4)}} = \frac{480}{\sqrt{9216}} = \frac{480}{96} = 5,
\end{equation}
as concluded by Jack.  This solution is not nearly as inspired or pleasant to look at as Jack's, but I think it provides the generality you hoped for.

---

**Edit.**  Here's some of the work we asked *Mathematica* to do.  Let's rewrite the equation as
\begin{equation}
1 = \sqrt{\left[4\left(\frac{r}{x}\right)^2-1\right]\left[4\left(\frac{r}{y}\right)^2-1\right]} + \sqrt{\left[4\left(\frac{r}{x}\right)^2-1\right]\left[4\left(\frac{r}{z}\right)^2-1\right]} + \sqrt{\left[4\left(\frac{r}{y}\right)^2-1\right]\left[4\left(\frac{r}{z}\right)^2-1\right]}.
\end{equation}
We can move the rightmost root to the LHS and square to obtain
\begin{equation}
\left(1 - \sqrt{\left[4\left(\frac{r}{y}\right)^2-1\right]\left[4\left(\frac{r}{z}\right)^2-1\right]}\right)^2 = \left[4\left(\frac{r}{x}\right)^2-1\right]\left(\sqrt{\left[4\left(\frac{r}{x}\right)^2-1\right]\left[4\left(\frac{r}{y}\right)^2-1\right]} + \sqrt{\left[4\left(\frac{r}{x}\right)^2-1\right]\left[4\left(\frac{r}{z}\right)^2-1\right]}\right)^2.
\end{equation}
Solve this for $4(r/x)^2$ and you'll find that
\begin{equation}
\frac{4x^2r^2}{y^2z^2} = 4\left(\frac{r}{y}\right)^2 + 4\left(\frac{r}{z}\right)^2 + 2\sqrt{4\left(\frac{r}{y}\right)^2-1}\sqrt{4\left(\frac{r}{z}\right)^2-1} - 2.
\end{equation}
Now isolate the remaining radicals and square again.  After factoring out $\frac{4r^2}{y^4z^4}$ you'll have an expression from which we can easily find $r^2$.

Comment: The denominator in the $xyz$-representation of $r$ factors (just like Heron's formula for the area of a triangle) as $$(x+y+z)(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)$$ which makes the $d_i$-representation not so terrible: $$r = \frac{(-d_1+d_2+d_3)(d_1-d_2+d_3)(d_1+d_2-d_3)}{\sqrt{(d_1+d_2+d_3)(3d_1-d_2-d_3)(3d_2-d_3-d_1)(3d_3-d_1-d_2)}}$$

Comment: @Blue Nice! I'll update the solution.

Comment: @AustinChristian Great answer - I was wondering whether you could take care of the Mathematica part. I have tried to show it, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I added some comments on how I did this part without *Mathematica*.  Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2):

We can derive the same general solution with an approach using some trigonometry.  I handled the consequent algebra manually. The idea is to write $A$ the area of hexagon in terms of the values of the angles and $s$ the side length of the hexagon, and then writing everything in terms of $A$.

[image: Figure 1]

Due to the parallel lines, Interior angle at $N = ∠ONQ +∠MNQ =∠RQN +∠PQN =$ Interior angle at $Q$.  The same applies to the other two pairs of interior opposite angles. Hence we have 3 pairs of equal angles, whose values we’ll call $\alpha,\beta,\xi$ , as colour-marked in the figure.

Now the Sum of interior angles in a hexagon $= 6\times180°-360° = 720°=4π= 2\left(\alpha+\beta+\xi\right)$. Thus:

$\beta=(\pi-\alpha)+(\pi-\xi) \tag{1} $

Geometrically, $\beta=\angle ZPO+\angle ZPQ\ =\ \angle POI+\angle PQJ\ =(\pi-\xi)+(\pi-\alpha) , where \ ZP:\parallel NO \ and \ RQ\  $.

Now $NR$ and $OQ$ divides the hexagon into a quadrilateral and 2 triangles. Since $NO$ is parallel to and is the same length as $RQ$, $RQ$ is a mere translation of $NO$, thus $NR\parallel OQ$ and $NOQR$ is a parallelogram. The Area of $NOQR = d_1s$.

$\triangle MNR$ and $\triangle POQ$ are both isosceles with $s$ as two of their side lengths and $\beta$ as the angle between the same two sides. If the base of $\triangle MNR = MR =\ s$, then the corresponding height $= NG = s\sin{\beta}$.  Thus the Area of $\triangle MNR =\triangle POQ=\ \frac{s^2\sin{\beta}}{2}$.

We can similarly divide the hexagon using $\alpha$ or $\xi$ as the angle of the isosceles triangles, ie the hexagon can be divided likewise in 3 ways (as shown by the blue, yellow and orange lines). Thus:

$A=d_1s+s^2\sin{\beta} \tag{2}$
$A=d_2s+s^2\sin{\xi} \tag{3}$
$A=d_3s+s^2\sin{\alpha} \tag{4}$

Consider $ A\ \mathrm{\mathrm{=}}\frac{1}{2}s\left(d_1+d_2+d_3\right)$.  For simplicity in the algebra that follows, let’s define $k:$

$$k\ =\ \frac{d_1+d_2+d_3}{2}=\ \frac{A}{s} \ \rightarrow \ s=\frac{A}{k} \tag{5}$$

Substitute (1) into (2), expand using the trigonometric angle-sum identity and simplify:

\begin{align}
A &=d_1s+s^2\sin{\left[(\pi-\alpha)+(\pi-\xi)\right]}\\  
 &=d_1s+s^2\left[\sin{(\pi-\alpha)}\cos{(\pi-\xi)}+\cos{(\pi-\alpha)}\sin{(\pi-\xi)}\right]\\  
&=d_1s+s^2(-\sin{\alpha}\cos{\xi}-\ \cos{\alpha}\sin{\xi})\\  
\end{align}
$A=d_1s-s^2\sin{\alpha}\cos{\xi}-s^2\cos{\alpha}\sin{\xi} \tag{6}$

Rearranging (3) gives $\sin{\xi}=\frac{A-d_2s}{s^2}$. Substituting (5) gives:

$$ \sin{\xi}=\left(A-\frac{d_2A}{k}\right)\left(\frac{k^2}{A^2}\right)=\frac{k(k-d_2)}{A} \tag{7}$$
Thus
$$\cos^2{\xi}=1-\frac{k^2{(k-d_2)}^2}{A^2} \tag{8}$$
Similarly,
$$\sin{\alpha}=\frac{k(k-d_3)}{A} \tag{9}$$
$$\cos^2{\alpha}=1-\frac{k^2{(k-d_3)}^2}{A^2} \tag{10}$$

Thus every term in (6) can be written in terms of $A$. So it's a matter of substituting and solving for $A$.

Substituting (5), (7) and (9) into (6) and simplifying, we can re-write (6):

$$A=\frac{d_1A}{k}-\frac{A(k-d_3)}{k}\cos{\xi}-\frac{A(k-d_2)}{k}\cos{\alpha}$$

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{k}{A}$ and rearranging:

$$-(k-d_2)\cos{\alpha}=(k-d_1)+(k-d_3)\cos{\xi}$$

Squaring both sides and substituting (8) and (10) give:

$${(k-d_2)}^2\left(1-\frac{k^2\left(k-d_3\right)^2}{A^2}\right)={(k-d_1)}^2+{(k-d_3)}^2\left(1-\frac{k^2\left(k-d_2\right)^2}{A^2}\right)+2(k-d_1)(k-d_3)\cos{\xi}$$

Expanding the brackets on both sides would eliminate the fraction terms on both sides, so the following remains:

$${(k-d_2)}^2={(k-d_1)}^2+{(k-d_3)}^2+2(k-d_1)(k-d_3)\cos{\xi}$$

Rearranging:

$$-2(k-d_1)(k-d_3)\cos{\xi}={(k-d_1)}^2+{(k-d_3)}^2-{(k-d_2)}^2$$

Squaring both sides then substituting in (8) give:

$$4{(k-d_1)}^2{(k-d_3)}^2-\frac{4{k^2(k-d_1)}^2{(k-d_3)}^2{(k-d_2)}^2}{A^2}=\left[{(k-d_1)}^2+{(k-d_3)}^2-{(k-d_2)}^2\right]^2$$

Thus:

$$A^2=\frac{4{k^2(k-d_1)}^2{(k-d_3)}^2{(k-d_2)}^2}{4{(k-d_1)}^2{(k-d_3)}^2-\left[{(k-d_1)}^2+{(k-d_3)}^2-{(k-d_2)}^2\right]^2}\tag{11}$$

assuming the denominator $>0$.

We could take the positive square root and stop here, and the equation is not too onerous. Or we could continue to write out using $d_i$ only without $k$, by simplifying then substituting $k=\ \frac{d_1+d_2+d_3}{2}$.

The denominator is a difference of two squares:

*Denominator*
\begin{align}  
& = \left[2\left(k-d_1\right)\left(k-d_3\right)\right]^2 -[\left(k-d_1\right)^2+\left(k-d_3\right)^2-{(k-d_2)}^2]^2 \\  
& = [2\left(k-d_1\right)\left(k-d_3\right)+\left(k-d_1\right)^2+\left(k-d_3\right)^2-{(k-d_2)}^2][-2\left(k-d_1\right)\left(k-d_3\right)+\left(k-d_1\right)^2+\left(k-d_3\right)^2-{(k-d_2)}^2]\times-1 \\  
& =-\left[{(k-d_1+k-d_3)}^2-{(k-d_2)}^2\right]\left[\left(\left(k-d_1\right)-\left(k-d_3\right)\right)^2-{(k-d_2)}^2\right] 
\end{align}

Since $k=\ \frac{d_1+d_2+d_3}{2},\  2k-d_1-d_3=d_2\ $. So:

*Denominator* $=-\left[{d_2}^2-{(k-d_2)}^2\right]\left[\left(d_3-d_1\right)^2-{(k-d_2)}^2\right]$

Factorise each difference of two squares and simplify to give:

*Denominator* $=k\left(k-2d_2\right)\left(d_3-d_1-d_2+k\right)\left(d_3-d_1+d_2-k\right)$

At this point we substitute $k=\ \frac{d_1+d_2+d_3}{2}$ and simplify to give:

*Denominator*
$$ = \frac{d_1+d_2+d_3}{2}\cdot\ \frac{d_1-3d_2+d_3}{2}\cdot\frac{-d_1-d_2+3d_3}{2}\cdot\frac{{-3d}_1+d_2+d_3}{2} \tag{12} $$

Substituting (5) into the numerator and (12) into the denominator of (11), and simplifying give:

$$A^2=\frac{\left(d_1+d_2+d_3\right)^2\left(-d_1+d_2+d_3\right)^2\left(d_1-d_2+d_3\right)^2\left(d_1+d_2-d_3\right)^2}{4\left(d_1+d_2+d_3\right)\left(3d_1-d_2-d_3\right)\left({-d}_1+{3d}_2-d_3\right)\left({-d}_1-d_2+3d_3\right)}$$

Thus, taking the positive square root:

$$\fbox{$A=\frac{\left(-d_1+d_2+d_3\right)\left(d_1+d_2-d_3\right)\left(d_1-d_2+d_3\right)\sqrt{d_1+d_2+d_3}}{2\sqrt{\left(3d_1-d_2-d_3\right)\left(3d_2-d_3-d_1\right)\left(3d_3-d_1-d_2\right)}}.$}$$

The square root of (11) provides an alternate form of this solution.