# Area of irregular equilateral hexagon

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

A hexagon has six equal sides, and opposite pairs of sides are parallel. The distances between the three pairs of opposite sides are $192$, $195$ and $237$ respectively.

What is the area of the hexagon?

This is a puzzle I came up with a few years ago, and Presh Talwalker featured it on his ‘Mind Your Decisions’ YouTube channel in 2020.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yy1EV9XCbtw) is the video. If this is not a duplicate ( I don't think so), I would encourage some editing of this question to be done , featuring this video as context. Then people can present solutions to be contrasted with Talwalkar's.

Comment: See a similar problem here [Area of a hexagon from the distances of the opposite sides](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336865/area-of-a-hexagon-from-the-distances-of-the-opposite-sides?rq=1)

Comment: @kabenyuk Haha, that was originally by me too: http://www.elliottline.com/puzzles-1/2015/11/6/puzzle-of-the-week-22-hex-agony

Comment: Thanks @ElliottLine, it would be very interesting and correct if you pointed this out in your question and commented on it somehow. A little history, I think, always brings a math puzzle to life.